# How does a 2D Array get traversed?

Tags: c++, arrays

I was working on [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/2d-array/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays) not too long ago and came up with this solution:

```
// Complete the hourglassSum function below.
int hourglassSum(vector<vector<int>> arr) {
    int max = INT_MIN;
    vector<int> sums;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) 
        {
            sums.push_back(arr[i][j] +
            arr[i - 1][j-1] +
            arr[i-1][j] +
            arr[i-1][j+1] +
            arr[i + 1][j - 1] +
            arr[i+1][j] +
            arr[i + 1][j + 1]); 

        }    
    }
    for (int g = 0; g  < sums.size(); g++) {
        cout << sums[g] << endl;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < sums.size(); k++) 
    {
        if (sums[k] > max)
        {
            max = sums[k];
        }
    }
return max;
}
```

I initially had a different solution, but changed the placement of i and j to make it work.  Which led me to the following question:  While traversing a 2D array is it okay to assume i is moving horizontally and j is moving vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"horizontal" and "vertical" are whatever you want them to be as long as your mental model is consistent. You can either think of `(x, y)` points where `x` is in the horizontal direction and `y` is in the vertical direction. Or you can think of the array as a matrix where `i` is the row number and `j` is the column number. Both of these points of view will work. Again, consistency is the important thing.

Comment: The lowest order (right most) dimension should be traversed the fastest to optimize cache lines.

Comment: @doug by "fastest" do you mean the inner most loop?

Comment: Yes. Innermost loop should reference the rightmost `[]` for best cacheline use.

Comment: @doug That is a good point. It still doesn't affect what we picture as "horizontal" or "vertical".

Comment: Your point about one's mental model being consistent is dead on. I was just pointing out the performance issues in how one arranges the dimensions. I've seen people use differing orientations. Doesn't matter as long as it's consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I checked this problem for fun. You can create some sort of mask to get current value of hourglass. Then you can just traverse array interchangeably left to right and right to left. When reaching right or left end go down. Something like this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

// Complete the hourglassSum function below.
int maskArray(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> &mask, std::vector<std::vector<int>> &array) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (auto& v : mask) {
        sum += array[v.first][v.second];
    }
    return sum;
}

void moveMaskLeft(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>  &mask) {
    for (auto& v : mask) {
        --v.second;
    }
}

void moveMaskRight(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>  &mask) {
    for (auto& v : mask) {
        ++v.second;
    }
}

void moveMaskDown(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>  &mask) {
    for (auto& v : mask) {
        ++v.first;
    }
}

int hourglassSum(vector<vector<int>> arr) {
    int maxSum = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> mask{{0,0}, {0,1}, {0,2},
                                                 {1,1},
                                          {2,0}, {2,1}, {2,2}};
    enum direction {R, L};
    direction dir = R;
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x) {
            int localSum = maskArray(mask, arr);
            maxSum = std::max(maxSum, localSum);
            if (dir == R) {
                if (x < 3)
                moveMaskRight(mask);
            } else {
                if (x < 3)
                moveMaskLeft(mask);
            }
        }
        dir = dir == R ? L : R;
        moveMaskDown(mask);
    }
  return maxSum;
}

int main()
{
    ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));

    vector<vector<int>> arr(6);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        arr[i].resize(6);

        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }

        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    int result = hourglassSum(arr);

    fout << result << "\n";

    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We don't care if you use stuff like `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` when your writing competitive programming code yourself, but if you're going to post here on SO, we would prefer you to use good practices as most people here want to be able to write maintainable code.